# Frequency coverage for first spectral channel of .fits cube?

Tags: fits, fits-header

A .fits cube has 3 dimensions, where the 1st axis is RA, 2nd axis is Declination and 3rd axis is frequency.

My question is rather simple, but causing pain none-the-less. Given a .fits cube, what is the frequency range (in Hz) of the first channel?

For example, if CRPIX3=1, CRVAL3=1E8 and CDELT3=0.5E8, does the first frequency channel cover 1E8 Hz to 1.5E8 Hz or 0.75E8 to 1.25E8 Hz?

Comment: No clue, but I will be surprised if that is universally the same. It should be documention which ships with your specific data

Answer (score 2):

After digging a little, I found the key sentence at the start of section 2.1.4 of [Greisen et al (2002)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-data_query?bibcode=2002A%26A...395.1061G&link_type=ARTICLE&db_key=AST), which reads:

> "Note that integer pixel numbers refer to the center of the pixel in
> each axis, so that, for example, the first pixel runs from pixel
> number 0.5 to pixel number 1.5 on every axis."

As an example, a coordinate system is defined in the .fits header to have a pixel size (CDELT1, CDELT2) of 1deg by 1deg, with a reference pixel coordinate (CRPIX1, CRPIX2) of (1, 1), whose coordinate value (CRVAL1, CRVAL2) is 30.0deg, +45.0deg. Consequently, the bottom left pixel (pixel coordinate of (1, 1) at its centre) will have a bottom left coordinate of 0.5pix, 0.5pix and 29.5deg, 44.5deg in real world coordinates and a top right coordinate of 1.5pix, 1.5pix and 30.5deg, 45.5deg.

*Thus, if the third, spectral axis is defined with a reference pixel (CRPIX3) of 1., reference value (CRVAL3) of 1E8Hz, and a pixel size (CDELT3) of 0.5E8, then that first spectral channel of the cube will cover 0.75E8 Hz to 1.25E8 Hz with an 'average' frequency value of 1E8 Hz.*